# Not able to find Debug menu option in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a stored procedure and I want to debug but I am not able to find the debug option on the menu. I tried running SSMS as administrator.

Comment: [T-SQL Debugger deprecated](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/04/24/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-0-released-for-general-availability/). You can use SSDT to debug a query.

Comment: In Visual Studio Community 2022 it is at Tools > SQL Server > New Query.   That opens a new file window.  In that window you get an Execute button with a tiny dropdown.  Select Execute With Debugger

Comment: I'm not able to see the Debug menu in SSMS 19.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You can still download and use the the older version of SSMS to get access to the debugger.
According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/transact-sql-debugger?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15)  you need version 17.9.1 or earlier which can be downloaded from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15#1791)